# Pointing out someone in a photograph

Tags: word-request

How should I refer to someone in a photograph with language? I know expressions like "the second girl on the right", but what should I say about "the first girl to the right"? Does "rightmost" sound natural?

Comment: The first girl on the right *or* The girl at far right

Comment: "Rightmost" is definitely acceptable and sounds natural to me but it sounds more like something an educated person would use. Using it in conversation with someone uneducated or unintelligent may make you sound pretentious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have 5 people in a row:

> Person 1 - Person 2 - Person 3 - Person 4 - Person 5

Then I would say it this way:

> Person 1 is the person on the left.
>   Person 2 is the second person from the left.
>   Person 3 is the third person from the left (or right).
>   Person 4 is the second person from the right.
>   Person 5 is the person on the right.

Answer (score 2):

*Does "rightmost" sound natural?*  It can, but rightmost wouldn't usually be heard in casual conversation.

StoneyB is correct: most people would say, "The girl on the right."  I've never heard, "The rightmost girl," although it does make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Some people would also say "The girl on the very right" to emphasize, especially if there are many people in the photo. This means roughly the same thing as rightmost and could also be used if you wanted to say something like "I was on the very edge of the cliff" to say that you were especially close to the edge.